# How to test paperclip validation with this relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, tdd, paperclip

I want to test the validations for the `Post` model.
For now, I have this:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  has_attached_file :image,
          styles: {
            thumb: "100x100#",
            small: "300x300>",
            large: "600x600>" }
            
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif'], allow_blank: true
  validates_attachment_size :image, less_than: 1.megabyte, allow_blank: true
end


#post model
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :assets, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets, allow_destroy: true
  attr_accessible :title, :description, :price, :status, :pageviews, :assets_attributes
end
```

the validations should ocurr for the post model.

## specs

```
# asset_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe Asset do
  
  it { should respond_to(:image_file_name) }
  it { should respond_to(:image_content_type) }
  it { should respond_to(:image_file_size) }
  
  it { should be_valid}
  
  describe "should validates the photo limit if photo upload is present" do
    it { should validate_attachment_size(:image).less_than(1.megabyte) }
  end
end

# post_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe Post do
  
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before { @post = user.posts.build(title: "Lorem ipsum welk", description: "Lorem ipsum", price: 150.000, status: 'pending') }
  
  subject { @post }
  
  
  it { should respond_to(:title) }
  it { should respond_to(:description) }
  it { should respond_to(:user_id) }
  it { should respond_to(:price) }
  it { should respond_to(:pageviews) }
  it { should respond_to(:status) }
  it { should respond_to(:user) }
  it { should respond_to(:assets) }
  its(:user) { should == user }

end
```

I have no clue about how to test such thing since I'm new to TDD.
Also I want to check for the existence of the `input` field for upload files on the `new_post_path`.

Thank you!